# Sending control keys with DDeltaSolution UIDeskAutomationSpy

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have been using DDeltaSolution's [UIDeskAutomationSpy](http://www.automationspy.com/uideskautomation/index.html)  to enhance some of my Coded UI testing, initially based on the MS Code UI test (cuit) framework.
However there is very limited documentation and even after using dotNetPeek to inspect the internals of the UIDeskAutomationSpy exe and associated dll, I can't see how to send control keys (Shift/Control/Alt) to a component.

There are two relevant methods

- SendKeys()
- SimulateSendKeys()

but both just take a string as input.

I've even got as far as thinking about trying to use [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) to try and modify the binaries (is this possible?), but this is a desperate measure. Does anyone know any better, or know of any better documentation?
This is a surprisingly powerful tool, but no-one seems to have heard about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive, but if I were you I'd try using the list of control key strings found [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) since automation spy is based on .NET. Let me know if it works!